# Is there a way to authenticate with nodejs and passport on a Nativescript Angular App?

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0, passport.js, nativescript

I have a `Node.js` backend where I implemented `Passport JS` for the authentication (Username-Password and Google). I have two front-ends, one SPA Web App in `Angular` and another mobile app in `{N} Angular`.

Authentication works fine in the Web app (see flow below):

#### front (web app)

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/auth/google">Google Sign In</a>
```

#### back

```
loginRouter.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : 'email' }));

loginRouter.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {successRedirect: "http://localhost:4200/home?blob=dataWithToken"}));
```

#### question

My question is the following, "how can I implement this flow in Nativescript?"

I tried to add a webview in my `{N}` app, but got the following error:

`google can't sign you in safely inside this app ...`

Any ideas? Any playgrounds available?

Comment: Google sign-in is recommend to be used with actual Browser not WebView, you have option to setup your app for Google sign in in your Google Developer Console, the redirect url will be your app's url scheme in such case.

Comment: @Manoj, do you have an idea on how to handle the `callback` url when the user has authenticated? For the web app I redirect to `http://localhost:4200/home?blob=dataWithToken`, but with `{N} app` I don't know how to do it... any ideas?

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned above. You handle here with URL scheme of your app, so the browser can open your app once it's authenticated, the setup has to be done on the developer console. [nativescript-oauth2](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-oauth2) plugin is a nice example for this implementation.

Comment: @Manoj, thanks a lot! I figured out how to make a call to the google strategy and redirect back to the app... thanks for the solution. I just need to find a way to retrieve the token now, couldn't figure out how to do it...

Comment: @Manoj, when `auth/callback/google` is called, I do this `res.redirect(`${urlScheme}:/auth?data=${token}`);` from the `backend`. How, on the `{N} app` can I retrieve this token?